# How do I add a variable to the legend without including it in the graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a value to the legend without adding it to the plot.

```
library(tidyverse)

gear_color <- c('black', "blue", "orange")
names(gear_color) <- c('3', '4', '5')

mtcars %>% 
  mutate(gear = factor(gear),
         vs = factor(vs)) %>% 
  filter(gear != 4) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(vs, fill = gear)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_wrap(~gear) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = gear_color)
```

[image: add_to_ggplot_legend]

How would I add Gear 4 to the legend without adding it to the plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scale_fill_manual` can take `drop` as parameter (`?scale_fill_manual`)

The `...`  - arguments passed onto discrete_scale

> drop - Should unused factor levels be omitted from the scale? The default, TRUE, uses the levels that appear in the data; FALSE uses all the levels in the factor.

So, we can add `drop = FALSE` in the last line

```
... +
    scale_fill_manual(values = gear_color, drop = FALSE)
```

As @eipi10 mentioned in the comments, an empty facet for `gear = 4` can be added similarly by include `drop = FALSE` in `facet_wrap`

-output

[image]

Comment: In cases where you do want an empty facet for gear==4, you can also add `drop=FALSE` to `facet_wrap()`.