# ggplot add variable to legend without including in plot (when using alpha)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a variable to the legend without including it in the plot.

I think problem doesn't occur when I don't use `alpha`(see: [How do I add a variable to the legend without including it in the graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55749847/how-do-i-add-a-variable-to-the-legend-without-including-it-in-the-graph/55750120#55750120))

```
library(tidyverse)

name_color <- c('black', "blue", "orange", "pink")
names(name_color) <- letters[1:4]

tibble(name = rep(letters[1:4], each = 2),
       respond = rep(c("yes", "no"), 4),
       n = rep(50, 8),
       me = "i") %>%
  filter(name != "c") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(me, n, fill = name, alpha = respond)) +
  facet_wrap(~name) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = name_color, drop = FALSE)
```

[image: add_to_legend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with `alpha`. The problem is the class of your data. When you use `tibble` to create your data, the `name` column is of class `character`. You need a `factor` class to "remember" the unused levels:

```
name_color <- c('black', "blue", "orange", "pink")
names(name_color) <- letters[1:4]
d = tibble(name = rep(letters[1:4], each = 2),
       respond = rep(c("yes", "no"), 4),
       n = rep(50, 8),
       me = "i") %>%

class(d$name)
# [1] "character"

d %>% mutate(name = factor(name)) %>%  
  filter(name != "c") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(me, n, fill = name, alpha = respond)) +
  facet_wrap(~name) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = name_color, drop = FALSE)
```

[image]

In the original question you link, you had the factor conversion explicitly, which is why it worked.

```
... %>% mutate(
  gear = factor(gear),
  vs = factor(vs)
) %>% ...
```